# Migrations successfull, but IIS thinks otherwise?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

So I started a new ASP.NET Core (2.2) project. I created an SQL Query, from there I created the MSSQL database, and from there I created the models and DBContext.

When I run this using IIS Express, everything works fine, but when I use IIS in the project properties, it complains about doing the migrations.

I did do the Add-Migrations  [-Context ]
After that I did the Update-Database [-Context ]

But when I try to go to an API route, it says that I still need to do the "Update-Database"...

What am I doing wrong? Also, is it possible to disable migrations for now? I did obviously Google how to disable migrations, but the solutions I find appear to be for the .NET Framework and not .NET Core...

Comment: what does your migration history table show? i think the table name is __migrationhistory

Comment: Are you shure that your code hass access to database? When you use IIS, It runs under user of AppPool. And if you not change it to your own account, it creates a new window user. This user can be has no access to database. And you programm show "Random" error.

Comment: Firswt of ll, I rather fix the issue, I can disable migrations, but I have to get it to work at some point in time anyway... The error I get does actually tell me to do "Add-Migration [name]" and than do "Update-Database", when I do both, it ends up telling me to "update-Database", where I'm stuck now... @TemaTre that could be the issue, but usually that generates a more clear error, at least from what I'm used to in .NET Framework web apps?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to clean project, remove last migration? Then clean database. (Or create new Empty database). Build your project, and run

```
update-database -target LastExistedMigrationName
```

So, after that execute

```
Add-Migration [name]
update-database
```

It will be the clear experiment. If something will goeas wrong, I will try to help you according to error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently .NET Core does not generate the same appropriate messages as .NET Framework does... My issue was the user right of my Application Pool. I choose to give the Application Pool my user account for development purposes, and everything works fine now!